# getting a two this values of my div (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery

I write a script in jquery: "add to cart". The problem is that the above script works, but not as it should be.

When I press the `addtobasket` div, it does a string of all names and prices. He does not get value **only** from this div.

I do not know how to do it, only to take it **this** value of div `cenaprzedmiotu` and div `nazwa`.
HTML/PHP (this is my product):

```
while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
    $i++;
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\"><section class = 'produkt'id = '$i'draggable = 'true' > ";
    echo "<div class=\"opis\"> <div class = \"nazwa\" style='margin-top:6px;'>".$row['nazwa']."</div> <div > < b > Cena: < /b> <span class=\"cenaprzedmiotu\">".$row['cena']."</span > PLN < /div> <div id = 'kategoriaproduktu'style = 'display: none;' > ".$row['kategoria']." < /div> </div><div class='addtobasket'><i class=\"fas fa-cart-plus\"></i > < /div>";
    echo "</section></div>";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".addtobasket", function(evt) {
    $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

    var suma = 0;
    var nazwa = $(".nazwa").text();
    var cena = $(".cenaprzedmiotu").text();
    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span></li>";

    $("#koszyk").append(li);
    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function() {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: try with `$(this).closest(".nazwa").text();`

Comment: when I did, it sees nothing: `var nazwa = $(this).closest(".nazwa").text();
        alert(nazwa);`

Comment: Then try `$(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();`

Comment: this working. dziękuję bardzo.

Comment: Nie ma za co :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
```

here you are more info about [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and 
  [.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)